# Take control of third-party app and send messages to its child window

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I'm trying to automate a 3rd party app using c# code. I know how to invoke the main window of the app through code using something like this..

```
word = textBox1.Text;
        Process myprocess = new Process();
        myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Cambridge Advanced  Learner's Dictionary - 3rd Edition.lnk";
        myprocess.Start();
```

but I dont know how to take control of its child windows and its different options and how to send the value of word to its child windows.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Twin: http://code.google.com/p/twin/

> Twin is a tool for automating Windows applications.  That
>   is, it enables you to write code to click buttons, enter text, and
>   view the results just as a user would.
>
> Twin was developed at eBay to allow automatic functional testing of
>   Windows software.  The design is based on the web automation tool
>   Selenium/WebDriver, and it can be used in similar ways.

Comment: is there any other way to use handlers or spy++

Comment: You can look at the source code, and see how they do it.  I'll be honest with you; this kind of automation is not easy to get right, so unless this is a learning exercise you're most likely going to be better off studying how they did it, rather than attempting to roll your own solution from scratch.

Comment: AutoIT---http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/
AutoIT will serve your purpose. when you download this tool you get some examples along with the tool. These examples will be very useful to write your own code to handle the windows GUI.